# Diferença entre var_dump e print_r

Tags: var-dump

Tenho uma dúvida simples e objetiva: Sempre nas minhas pesquisas por aí, noto que alguns programadores usam `var_dump()` e outros usam `print_r` (como eu).

> Qual a diferença entre `print_r()` e `var_dump()`, sendo que ambos
>   trazem "praticamente" o mesmo resultado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente as diferenças entre `print_r()`e `var_dump()` são que o segundo além de exibir o valor/estrutura da variável mostra seu tipo e o tamanho no caso de strings. Não retornar valor da expressão/variável nesse caso [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) é recomendado.

var_dump()

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'teste');
var_dump($arr);
```

Saida:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'teste' (length=5)
```

print_r()

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'teste');
print_r($arr);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => teste
)
```