# Como alterar uma imagem no banco de dados pelo ID?

Tags: php, imagem, upload

Olá, tudo na boa com vocês? Comecei a pouco tempo um formulário onde são enviadas algumas informações para o banco de dados, porem quando vou editar alguma informação ele altera tudo menos a imagem, antes ele so apagava e deixava em branco, agora ele não faz nada... se alguem puder da uma força agradeço desde já.

### pagina de consulta

```
<?php

//inicia a conexao com o banco 

include_once("conexao.php"); 

//filtro para pesquisa por palavra chave 

$filtro = isset($_GET['filtro'])?$_GET['filtro']:"";

//consulta slq
$sql = "SELECT * FROM eqp";
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$registros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

?>

<html lang ="pt-br">         

  <head>                      

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Filtro de Busca </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../agoravai/edicao/form_consultate.css">


  </head>


      <body>

         <div class="container">

            <nav>

                <ul class="menu">

                   <li></li>
                 <a href="inicio.php"><li>Inicio</li></a>
                    <a href="filtros.php"><li>Filtros:</li></a>
                    <a href="telalog_ed_cons.php"><li>Editar Dados:</li></a>





                </ul>

            </nav>

           <section>


              <h1>Consulta por Formularios Enviados Realizada:</h1>
              <br>
              <hr>





               <?php

               //verifica os itens do banco e os exibe
                print" <h1>$registros Registros encontrados:</h1>";

               while($exebirregistros = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

                    $codigo = $exebirregistros[0];
                  $nome = $exebirregistros[1];
                   $setor =$exebirregistros[2];
                   $equipamento =$exebirregistros[3];
                   $numeroserie =$exebirregistros[4];
                   $numeropatrimonio =$exebirregistros[13];
                   $locais =$exebirregistros[5];
                   $motivo =$exebirregistros[6];
                   $enviando = $exebirregistros[7];
                   $recebendo =$exebirregistros[8];
                   $defeito =$exebirregistros[9];
                   $transporte =$exebirregistros[10];
                   $dataid =$exebirregistros[11];
                   $dataret =$exebirregistros[12];
                    $numeropatrimonio =$exebirregistros[13];
                   $arquivo =$exebirregistros[14];
                   $ordemdeservico =$exebirregistros[15];

//alerme para data de envio e entrega de equipamento

$data_atual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$data_expiracao = new DateTime($dataret);

$intervalo_em_dias = $data_atual->diff($data_expiracao);

echo $intervalo_em_dias->format('<h4>%R%a DIAS PARA VENCER O RETORNO</h4>');


           echo (" <table border='2px' cellpacing='15px'>

           <tr>
            <td>Codigo: </td>
        <td>Nome:</td>
            <td>Setor:</td>
            <td>Equipamento:</td>
            <td>Anexo N° ".$codigo.":</td>
            <td>Numero de Serie:</td>
            <td>Numero de Patrimonio:</td>
            <td>Local de Envio:</td>
            <td>Motivo Envio:</td>
            <td>Quem esta Enviando:</td>
            <td>Quem esta Recebendo:</td>
            <td>Defeito:</td>
            <td>Meio de Transporte:</td>
            <td>Data ida:</td>
            <td>Data Retorno:</td>


            </tr> ");      

    echo  ("

<tr>

    <td>" . $codigo . " </td><br>

    <td>" . $nome . " </td>

    <td>" . $setor . " </td>

    <td>" . $equipamento . " </td>

    <td class= ok >" . "<img src='upload/".$arquivo."'width=50px height=50px /></td>

    <td>" . $numeroserie . " </td>

    <td>" . $numeropatrimonio . " </td>

    <td>" . $locais . " </td>

    <td>" . $motivo . " </td>

    <td>" . $enviando . " </td>

    <td>" . $recebendo . " </td>

    <td>" . $defeito . " </td>

    <td>" . $transporte . " </td>

    <td>" . $dataid . " </td>

    <td>" . $dataret . " </td>


    </tr>
    <td> <a href='ed_cons_.php?codigo=" . $codigo . "'>editar</td>



    ")
        ;


               }  



               mysqli_close($conexao);

               ?>

                <br>


           </section>


         </div>



     </body>


</html>
```

### ed_cons_.php

```
<?php
//inicia a conexao com o banco 

include ("conexao.php"); 
?>
<html lang ="pt-br">      
<html>
  <head>                     
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../agoravai/css/estilo.css">
  </head>       
            <body>

                    <nav>


                            <ul class="menu">
                            <a href="../agoravai/inicio.php"><li>Inicio</li></a>
                             <a href="../aff/consultaeqp.php"><li>Consulta</a>

                               </ul>

                   </nav>



              </body>




        <?php
 //recebe o codigo da pag de consulta        
$iden = isset($_GET['iden'])?$_GET['iden']:"";      

$iden = $_GET ['codigo'];

// consulta no banco de dados         
$sql = "select * from eqp where codigo = '$iden'"; 
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$registros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

//recebe os dados    

$codigo = $linhas ['codigo'];
$arquivo = $linhas['arquivo'];



            echo ("


            <tr>

              <form method='post' action='salva_ed.php''>
            <td>Codigo:</td><td> <input type='text' name='codigo' value='"  .   $codigo . "'> </td>  

              <td>Arquivo em anexo: <input type='file' class= 'anexo' name='arquivo'> </td>

              <br><br>  

             </tr>

      <br><br>

      <input type='submit' class='bnt salvar' value='Salvar'> 



 ");


        }

        ?>


</html>
```

### salva_ed

```
<?php
//inicia conexão com o banco 
include ("conexao.php"); 

 // recebe o codigo do registro 

$iden = isset($_POST['iden'])?$_POST['iden']:""; 

// codigo registro 

$iden = $_POST ['codigo']; 

// aqui seria onde ele veifica se existe algo no campo arquivo e o substitui por um valor em branco 
if($arquivo == ""){
    $query =("update eqp set arquivo = '' WHERE codigo='$iden'");
}else{

// aqui seria onde fazia o update da imagem, dando um novo nome e movendo para a pasta de upload 
 if(isset($_FILES['imagem']))
   {
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eqp WHERE codigo = '$id' LIMIT 1");
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão
    $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
    $new_name = $resultado['foto']; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
    $dir = 'upload'; //Diretório para uploads

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo

   }

$imagem = $new_name;

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE eqp set arquivo = '$imagem' WHERE codigo='$id'");

  $result1 = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql,$query);

  // Verifica se o comando foi executado com sucesso
  if(!$result1)
    echo "Registro NÃO alterado.";
  else
    echo "Registro Alterado com sucesso.";
}
?>
```

Eu acho que problema esta nessa pagina onde salva, pois eu vi que teria que apagar primeiro a imagem do banco para ai fazer o upload porem ate agora sem sucesso (na pagina de edição é recebida mais variáveis porem como só estou tendo problema em editar a imagem deixei apenas o codigo e imagem para ser exibida para facilitar o entendimento  )

Comment: Olá, seja bem-vindo!
Eu acredito que o título da sua pergunta não condiz com o que você está perguntando. pois de fato vc não está fazendo upload de uma imagem no banco de dados(blob) vc apenas salva um nome de arquivo e está tendo problemas com o algorítimo.
Vc pode usar o código `var_dump($imagem,$_FILES); exit;`   antes do último update para verificar o que está saindo nessas variáveis, é provavel que ela esteja retornando um valor inválido.

Comment: olá leonancarvalho, muito obrigado pela atenção!! Cara, não entendi muito bem o código que você me mandou, qual seria a função dele? desculpa a igorancia haha mas com o tempo a gente aprende ne.. eu o adicionei como você disse, mas ainda continua o mesmo problema está dando esse erro "Notice: Undefined variable: arquivo in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 14" como se ele não recebesse nenhuma informação da pagina de edição.

Comment: Tranquilo @noobphp! O var_dump serve para você depurar a saida de variáveis através de um dump(impressão na tela) mais detalhes aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172775/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-var-dump-e-print-r

É uma função muito útil para depuração durante o desenvolvimento. Como imaginava o motivo pelo qual não está salvando é porque sua variável `$arquivo`  está vazia, reveja a lógica de tratamento pois ela está incorreta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando informar no seu formulário o atributo enctype="multipart/form-data"

**ed_cons_.php**

```
<form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" action='salva_ed.php''>
```

Quando se envia arquivos é necessário especificar essa tag no formulário.

Comment: ola Vitor, bem notado cara haha não tinha percebido que faltava a função  mas ainda esta dando erro, agora está aparecendo a seguinte informação : "Notice: Undefined variable: new_name in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 33
NULL array(1) { ["arquivo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "images.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xammp\tmp\php4720.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(7225) } } " tentei definir ela assim "$new_name =$_FILES['arquivo']; porem ainda da erro

Comment: Pelo que parece é apenas uma notificação que a variável não foi inicializada. No salva_ed após o include coloque a seguinte linha e vê se sai esse aviso.
$new_name = "";

Comment: primeiramente muito obrigado pela atenção Vitor !! vamos la, adicionei ela logo em baixo do include e esta retornando a seguinte mensagem : "string(0) "" array(1) { ["arquivo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "images.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xammp\tmp\php4B83.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(7225) } } "

Comment: Provavelmente você deixou um var_dump ou um print_r no código, estes comandos são usados para imprimir mensagens na tela, nesta caso parece estar imprimindo a váriavel $_FILES

Comment: sim, realmente eu tinha um var_dump no meu codigo, logo apos a variavel $imagem=$new_imagem; apos retirar está retornando o seguinte: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 38

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 40

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 40
Registro NÃO alterado.